# Semicolon error

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I got an error saying insert a semicolon at the end:

```
Assets/melee.js(13,17): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end
```

My unity3d script:

```
#pragma strict
var TheDammage : int = 50;
var Distance = float;
var MaxDistance : float = 1.5;
var TheMace : Transform;

function Update() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
        GetComponent TheMace.<Animation>().Play("Attack");
    }
}

function AttackDammage() {
    //Attack function
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (TheSystem.transform.position, TheSystem.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit)) {
        Distance = hit.distance;
        if (Distance < MaxDistance) {
            hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDammage", TheDammage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }==
}
```

Comment: Is the `==` on the second-last line supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your script, just remove the `==` that probably got added when pressing that key instead of backspace. Happens all the time...